# Dictionary string key containing comma as binding path

Tags: wpf

I am programmatically making bindings for `DataGridColumn` like:

```
var path = "DictObj[" + key_str + "]";
column.Binding = new Binding(path);
```

It usually works fine, but when `key_str` contains a commma, cells in the column shows nothing. I tried (without much considerations) `var path = "'...'"`, `"\'...\'"`, `"{}{...}"`, `"'{}...'"`, or, `"DictObj[[" + key_str + "]]"`, but in vain.

As the `key_str` is also used for displaying purpose, I do not want it to remove its comma. Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The path you pass to a `Binding` is used to construct a `PropertyPath` object. That object treats a comma (,) as a special character. You need to escape it by placing a caret (^) character in front of the comma. So, your path var should look something like this:

```
var path = "DictObj[" + key_str.Replace(",", "^,") + "]";
```

According to [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.100).aspx): "Inside indexers ([ ]), the caret character (^) escapes the next character."

Note: Creating a similar binding from XAML actually requires two escape characters (^\) in front of the comma:

```
{Binding Path=Dict[Some^\,String]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Is there any other character that needs this kind of escaping? I've tried concatenating a `[` and a `]` and it worked, even though it's the delimiter for the dictionary indexer.

Comment: I am not sure what all the rules are exactly, but there is a section on the page I linked called "Escapes for Property Path Strings" that covers characters that need to be escaped and how to escape them.